# Do my publications help my department/university?

Tags: publications, independent-researcher, lecturer

I am currently a mathematics lecturer at a state university in the US. I still do research and put a lot of effort into publications, although it is not required for my position. My question is: Will my publications (in good journals) be seen as a positive by the math department and/or university overall? Do they gain any benefits from my research? Is there some baseline for number of publications that they need to meet for funding, etc?

Answer (score 3):

(Although OP is in the US, the question doesn't have a "united-states" tag, so...)

In England and Wales, there's a pot of government money called ["QR funding"](https://re.ukri.org/funding/quality-related-research-funding/), which is allocated to universities in proportion to the quality and quantity of their faculty members' research publications, as measured in an episodic exercise called ["REF"](https://www.ref.ac.uk/).

Answer (score 2):

The publications of faculty add to the reputation of a university, more specifically, to a department. But there is no direct effect. In funding for a particular project it will help if they can show productive activity in that area and your papers might be cited. Likewise having research seminars in a topic is helpful. But there aren't cutoffs or similar.

Regular faculty are in a good position for getting salary increases and/or reduced teaching loads, but this is probably less available to a lecturer. But it might give you an edge in a number of ways. It might not be possible to bypass regular procedures to hire you for a TT position, but people will look favorably upon an application. Likewise, if you work collaboratively with the tenured faculty you will be in a good position to get good letters when it is time to move on.

So, benefits: yes. Formulas: no.

Answer (score 0):

One positive side-effect of your publications pertain to world university rankings.

All such higher education rankings I know of take into account the number of scholarly publications (and citations to these publications). They do so in two ways:

First, as inclusion criteria for institutes to be listed in a ranking (e.g. the *THE World University Ranking* demands more than 150 publications in a single year [[p. 6]](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/breaking_news_files/the_2021_world_university_rankings_methodology_24082020final.pdf); or the *CWTS Leiden Ranking* ranks universities only if they have at least 800 publications in 2015-8 [[see here]](https://www.leidenranking.com/information/universities)).

And secondly, publications (and citations) serve as as core performance indicators. For instance, publications weigh 20% of a journal's score in the *Shanghai Ranking* (according to their [Ranking Methodology](http://www.shanghairanking.com/ARWU-Methodology-2020.html)).

And these university rankings, in turn, have their real-life impact - [as many studies show](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=impact%20of%20world%20university%20rankings).

Comment: Getting your university from rank 1201 to 1198 does not buy you even one coffee, and helping to get into the lower fifth of such a ranking is equally worthless.